# Multiple layouts in NextJS or conditional css import

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I'm working on moving legacy app to the Nextjs. The app has two layouts: **public** and **admin** part. Every layout has it's own css files. Because of the nextjs restrictions when you can import css only in custom _app.js file I can't split layouts. I don't want to include admin css to the public layout and vice versa. What can I do in this case?

I was trying to use `styled-jsx`, but it brought more problems. I can't wrap the whole css file with thouthands of lines with ``` css.globe`` ```  because there are a lot of errors, such as `we don't support nesting` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the files in the /public folder and then just manage the  for the css manually. A good place for manually managing the included styles would be a custom _document.jsx page.

Note that you work around next by doing this. The files won't get bundled with your other css-files. They will also be available to the public by url.

Comment: What if I need postcss features like purge css?

Comment: Just use postcss natively through a npm-script or through the cli. You could even create a npm-script that does both: Run your custom postcss-buildchain AND start next. This can be done by a entry in your package.json:
{"scripts": [ {"dev": "node scripts/postcssBuildchainWhatever.css && next"}]}
This is just the cost of not using the buildchain provided by next. I don't think there is a safe way to utilize next only for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -2):

Convert the import to a [CSS Module](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css) by changing the name from (for example) `public.css` to `public.module.css`.

Then import it as an object.

```js
import styles from 'path-to/public.module.css'
```

And use it with the className attribute.

```jsx
<div className={styles.whatever}></div>
```

Note, the contents of `public.module.css` are just stock CSS.

```css
.whatever { /*...*/ }
```

You can apply a conditional style with a ternary.

```jsx
<div className={someBoolean ? styles.whatever : ''}>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the styles are also namespaced and things that work in global css don't work in css modules.

Answer (score -4):

You can define two layout components with `dynamic` and switch then in `_app.js`. This [article](https://web.dev/code-splitting-with-dynamic-imports-in-nextjs/) shows the features of `dynamic`.

On the other hand, `we don't support nesting` may caused by applying `sass/scss` file of `css` compiler in `styled-jsx`. You could try to make `styled-jsx` to support [sass/scss features](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support).

#### _app.js

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

#### Layout.js

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const mapLayoutToComponent = {
  public: dynamic(import("./layouts/Public")),
  admin: dynamic(import("./layouts/Admin"))
}

const Layout = props => {
  const [layoutState, setLayoutState] = React.useState('public');
  const Component = mapLayoutNameToComponent[layoutState];

  return <Component>{props.children}</Component>
}
```

#### layouts/Public.js

```
import '../styles/public.css';

const Public = (props) => {
  return <>{props.children}</>
};
```

#### layouts/Admin.js

```
import '../styles/admin.css';

const Admin = (props) => {
  return <>{props.children}</>
};
```

Comment: I separated layouts, I even don't need dynamic import. And there is no sass\scss in my theme css file. It's simple big css file, that works if I just include it in raw html file without any web packs.

Comment: And it says ```Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to pages/_app.tsx. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).```

Comment: Not working. you'll get an error trying that.